# Javascript method to find number of milliseconds from 1970-01-01?

Tags: javascript, date, timestamp, compare, utc

Say, I have a date

```
var dt = new Date('2012-01-01');
```

Is there a method in Javascript to return number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01?
For this particulat date it would return 1325376000000

For this purpose, there is a method  "toUTC()" that runs in Chrome only. I know this because i can do that in Chrome's console. See screen attached below:

[image]

However, When I search about this method on the internet, I don't find it and it doesn't work in Firefox either which is very wierd and I am very confused.

Anyhow, if you know any way to get this, will be really appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the getTime function:

```
var dt = new Date('2012-01-01');
var time = dt.getTime();
```

Comment: `Date.now()` works too.

Answer (score 1):

You can get it with:

```
new Date('2012-01-01').getTime();
```

The `getTime()` method returns the number of milliseconds between midnight of January 1, 1970 and the specified date.